# how to convert coordinates to geoPoint format?

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates

I am getting latitude and longitude coordinates in following format.

```
<coordinates>N44 47.975 E20 17.052</coordinates>
```

Can anyone guide me how to convert it to geoPoint format to display it on map?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) explains everything:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(47.975 * 1E6), (int)(17.056 * 1E6))
```

Comment: so in this case i dont need to take care of N44 & values E20 right?

Comment: I think it's more likely that the coordinates are 44 degrees 47.975 minutes N, 20 degrees 17.052 minutes E. Making it approximately 44.799 degrees N, 20.2842 degrees E

Comment: This answer is very, very wrong. In face, you've completely dropped the lat/lon degree and just used minutes and seconds... so, how is this the accepted answer?