# How to convert from ScreenCoordinates to GeoPoints

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

i use `onScrollChanged(int pL, int pT, int pOldl, int pOldt)`  to limit the MapView Scrolling.
How can i convert from pL and pT to GeoPoint?

Thanks.

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701824/how-to-convert-coordinates-to-geopoint-format

Comment: I saw that post.                                                   i need to convert different values (int values) , for example (101332, -98790, 101388, -98590)      thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Call `getProjection()` on your `MapView`, and using the resulting [`Projection`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection.html) object to convert `fromPixels()` to your `GeoPoint`.

Comment: When i try to convert from pL and pT, i got wrong GeoPoints values:  GeoPoint gp = (GeoPoint)getProjection().fromPixels(pL,pT);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the method `mapView.setScrollableAreaLimit(BoundingBoxE6)`
to set the scrollable